# Google Maps Api v2 error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var mymarkers= []; //array

function createMarker(point,html,ref){  
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    mymarkers[ref] = marker;
    GEvent.addListener(newmarker,'click',function(){newmarker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);});
    map.addOverlay(newmarker);
}
```

This function works well, it adds a marker to the map no problem, but when trying to use mymarkers[] array of markers they have not been stored?

Is there a validator to check the GMarker is nice and clean?

google maps main.js throws a wobbly:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e_' of undefined
```

Comment: Sorry, ref was empty. I will checks args more carefully in future! Googles api error messages could be better.

Comment: You have a point about the error messages. However that is an unfortunate side-effect of [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification). In fact, many JavaScript libraries provide a "debug" non-minified version for the developers to be able to receive meaningful non-garbled error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `mymarkers[ref]` instead of `newmarker` (which is undefined). Actually, the function could be simplified further as follows:

```
var mymarkers = [];

function createMarker (point, html, ref) {  
    mymarkers[ref] = new GMarker(point);;
    GEvent.addListener(mymarkers[ref], 'click', function () {
        mymarkers[ref].openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    map.addOverlay(mymarkers[ref]);
}
```